Why are comments posing as answers allowed here?
For example, the user Conifold’s entire action history is full of many opinionated (even if researched) comments posing as answers. This creates issues because even if he is a long time contributor, any inaccuracies cannot be easily and meticulously responded to given the nature of a comment chain. It also allows someone to escape criticism and not actually have to expand on their reasoning process when answering questions. Note that comments cannot be downvoted and long time contributors can get atleast some upvotes no matter what because they are as such.
So, why is this allowed? Can anyone do this? Should we all just start writing our own brief answers to every question in a comment section where the intended purpose is to point out how the question can be changed or clarified, and not to actually answer the question? Laziness cannot be considered an adequate reason if users such as this have the time to be writing thousands of comments for 7+ years.
Note that one of the moderators here explicitly says the rules should be broken here:
“@tkruse. Exactly right: the particular user is notable for the excellence his contributions. Flexibility is called for: It is clear that the user prefers usually to answer in comments; and I would rather have his answers in comments than not all. This case is exceptional, however; and Lowri is right that PSE guidance is for answers not to be given in comments”
EDIT: Lowri posted a similar question in the comments but I think this should be its own discussion given that the moderators do not actually remove this user’s comments almost ever, despite multiple call outs.  Secondly, this question asks why this seems to be allowed, not whether it is allowed.

Because this site is incredibly loosely moderated (by both mods and regular users), and allows all kinds of stuff that other sites wouldn't.

Request for clarification: are you complaining about things that are answers posted in the comments section, or things that are comments posted the answers section? I addressed the former. For the letter, downvote it or flag it as "not an answer "

You ask:

Why are comments posing as answers allowed here?

They probably shouldn't be, but you're not fooling anyone by making this about some general issue regarding "comments-as-answers". You have a problem specifically with Conifold since by your own admission he doesn't argue with you.
You say:

For example, the user Conifold’s entire action history is full of many opinionated (even if researched) comments posing as answers. This creates issues because even if he is a long time contributor, any inaccuracies cannot be easily and meticulously responded to given the nature of a comment chain.

If you want to rebut an answer Conifold provides in a comment, simply create an answer and address the OP with your views there. Your answer will speak for itself (or won't depending on your content). You seem to evince a need to debate people in the comments, and I certainly don't have a problem with that. But ultimately, this site doesn't provide the One-True-Answer. What it provides is a forum for people with an interest in philosophy (and often not much knowledge of the topic) to put forth their own answer. People vote. Posts open and close, and third-parties who are interested in the question must weigh for themselves the chaos that surrounds the process.
But your post has an axe to grind. You said to me:

Conifold’s “answers” are opinionated comments that he doesn’t respond to when inaccuracies are called out.

It annoys you that Conifold doesn't want to participate in your grievances. Personally, I don't have a problem engaging in some back and forth, particularly with users who haven't formally studied philosophy, such as yourself, because it's an opportunity to test my constructs with people who use "common sense" to make arguments. But Conifold needn't engage you at all. This site is not a debating forum. If you want to debate, go over to thephilosophyforum.com. This site is to provide canonical responses to fact-seeking questions. I've watched Conifold respond to crticism, a few of my own, for over five years, and he (perhaps she) has always obliged some back and forth. His answers are here.
Conifold's answers are some of the best answers provided since it is obvious that he is a professional academic. His answers are well sourced, tend to appeal to lines of arguments used in references, and generally require some research to even understand. But he is under no obligation to contribute, no obligations to debate you, and beyond the reach of all but moderators. I will repeat myself. I learn more about philosophy from his comments then I do most contributors answers.
So, you can foment discontent with Conifold (and others time to time) and moderators who may or may not be in breach of some obligation by the larger organization. Or you can spend your time reading philosophy and engage in quietism. If you are genuinely discontent with the moderators, then you have a right to run for election, become a moderator, and make changes. But other than that, know that I prefer readings from those who have philosophical expertise. And if that comes in comments rather than answers, so be it. Not all contributions are created equal. Have you compared your answers to his answers systematically? There's a tremendous difference in quantity and quality, and it's in his favor.

Good answer, and I would put a finer point on it: the answer to the question "Why is Conifold allowed to post answers in comments" is "Because Conifold's contributions are, by the standards of Phil.SE, of an exceptionally high quality."

Summary
They aren't allowed. The solution is to flag with a custom message and/or convert to a community wiki answer. One user might be a special case, but the community has rejected a previous attempt to explain/document this.
Comments are not the place for answers
Can moderators clarify whether this site allows answers in comments?
The moderator view:

Comments are not meant to be used to answer, even partially
...
Hence, the moderation policy should be to delete all comments that do not serve the purpose of improving the post, not least because it is network-wide policy and integral to the idea of how SE is supposed to work like

The solution as a user
I frequently turn answers that I see in comments into community wiki answers and/or flag them for moderator removal.
When I used to see usernames, I can attest that I certainly converted several of Conifold's comments into answers and successfully flagged moderators to delete the obsolete comments (contradicting the assertion that "literally 100%" of their comments posing answers are "not removed at all"). I would not be surprised if I have since done the same unbeknownst to me. I also occasionally flag without converting, and these are also generally successful, but not always: Can a moderator please explain the appropriateness of this comment?
But don't add to the mess. Just as comments are not the place for answers, they also aren't the place for debate or secondary discussion about an answer that improperly arises in a comment. We all know comments cannot be downvoted, so upvotes on a comment do not stand for a sign of quality as an answer.
An undocumented "exception" that the community has rejected as existing
Regarding one particular user,  I previously proposed to document the "exception." The community rejects that explanation or any attempt to document the exception: This site tolerates the following users writing answers in comments
Reasons the community has given for retaining Conifold's answers in comments have been discussed before, in that post.

So why are literally 100% of comments by the mentioned user which seem to be often posing answers not removed at all? I’m guessing it’s because of the fact that the user is a long time contributor but as per policy, that should not be a valid reason

The community is under no obligation to explain or document anything, as far as I can tell. The moderators are under no obligation to explain or document anything as far as I can tell. I'm not against in principle following more stringent rules, but after five years, nothing has changed, and absent an intervention by SE itself (like cleaning house on the entire collection of monitors or imposing some sort of demands on the moderators), it just doesn't seem likely to change.

@syed Let's say you win the argument; it shouldn't happen. Then what? Has your victory in argument created any real change? Will get what you want? Probably not. If you have a more concrete course of action, march on!

No. I just wanted to make it clear that my personal position is not aligned against following the rules. We have moderators who are democratically elected for life, and are relatively unaccountable in the sense of traditional constituency. I'm always interested in any discourse that would fundamentally would improve the forum. :D I only commented because I was a proponent when you raised the objection yourself.

@Syed First, the quality and breadth of this user's contribution far exceed your own here, even if we only count the comments written since you made this account. Please tone it down. That said, this answer covers everything I'd have to say on the matter. To me, it looks like you have problems with a user's disagreement with your own views, regardless of how well-founded the opposing view is. That it's presented in comments just gives you a justification to turn on it on formal grounds since you have no argumentative way to come by.

@JD why do you care about my motivations? I just want the moderators to acknowledge that he’s breaking the rules. But instead, you and Phillip seem to care more about my motivations than addressing this.

@Lowri then they should do something about it instead of being cowards

After reading the comment threads here, I think I need to add an aspect not mentioned yet.
Why is it not recommended (and that is the actual wording in the help center) to answer in comments?
It is primarily because comments were meant to be short-lived "post-its" to the actual post, as the help center puts it. Thus, the helpful content can easily be lost, may it be due to being moved to chat or simple deletion.
In practice, comments are not as transient as they were originally designed, a pattern which is by far not only true for Philosophy.SE. Just check older posts on Meta.SE if you don't believe me.
Thus, while it would certainly be preferable if useful content would be posted solely in separate posts, I do not think it is the capital crime you're making it here.
The user expressed a preference to post in comments and not have the content in answers, maybe because they feel that a proper answer would require more research and careful consideration than they can provide due to time restrictions. The more you know about philosophy, the more often you realise that you cannot provide easy answers here without intellectual dishonesty. And it takes a lot of time to write a good answer if your standards are formed by years of academic practice. Yet, even the content off the top of the hat of a well-educated person can prove more helpful than the carefully thought-about long answers pf someone with much less experience in the field, no matter how they feel it to be insufficient for a full-blown answer.

I don't think this is being done deliberately, either by the author or by the moderators.
Speaking for myself: I often start to write a comment, then later realize that I have written enough useful content that I should move it to an answer.
What I do realize, I am trying to get better about moving it. But if it starts as a supplemental idea or clarificationrather than a direct attempt to answer the question, it will still often start as a comment.
If you think a comment looks like it ought to be an answer, standard peer practice on stock exchange is to post a polite comment after it saying something like "hey, @@user, that looks like [the start of] a good Answer to me" to encourage them to move it into the answers section. Then give them time to notice the comment and respond. In some cases, you can assist by quoting the comment, with attribution, into an answer that you post. (It would be nice if there was a button that turned comments into answers while keeping ownership with the comment's author, but I'm not sure even the moderators have that ability.)
Answers in comments are mostly discouraged because comments may vanish at any time, and since the goal is to build a library of answers having the best answer be in a comment is a moderate disservice to the community. It also makes comments on that answer harder to associate with it, awards the author fewer points for upvotes, and makes it impossible to downvote. Outside of those details, and setting a bad example for other users, they are mostly harmless. It's worth gently pointing them out when they happen, either as a peer or by flagging them for the moderators. But I have a hard time getting exercised about them. I don't know whether that is because I'm also guilty, or because I don't buy into the whole gamificarion aspect of Stack Exchange.
The system is not perfect. If we work as a community to help each other, rather than sniping at each other, we can make it better.

why do you think it’s not deliberate when I listed an example of a moderator literally saying he allows this user’s comments to remain as answers?

I do not think it is deliberate on the part of the author of that material. I do grant that the editor in question has decided that forcing the recopying is more work than they want to invest for the minor gain achieved.  As I said, I am not convinced I disagree with that, though I agree with you that the current state is suboptimal.  Givien a proper a migrate-to-answer button I would advocate clicking it. In the absence of that, I put this in the category of "moderating is already a near - thankless job and I think there are higher priorities for them to work on."
